# Black screen and file explorer on roaming profiles

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, roaming-profile

question about roaming profiles in AD.

There was a problem with a message that the mobile profile limit had been exceeded, so I changed the limit in GPO from 30MB to 2GB (maybe a bit too much xd). I don't have much experience with roaming profiles. I would like to leave form roaming profiles, but actions are needed. After this change, users have a black screen after logging in, only file explorer opens automatically.
Plus, the user logs in for a long time, but that's normal because he's loading his own files.

What will you benefit? (apart from switching from these mobile profiles to something else...)

AD: Windows Server 2016
Hosts: Win10/11